# why am i getting segmentation fault when i run this code?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

void avg_sum(double a[], int n, double *avg, double *sum)
{
    int i;
    sum = 0;
    printf("%f", *sum);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        *sum += a[i];
    *avg = *sum/n;
}


int main()
{
    double arr[2] = {0.0,1.0};
    double *sum;
    double *avg;
    int n = 2;
    avg_sum(arr, n, avg, sum);
    printf("...Done...\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Tried using both GCC(https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) and clang(from repl.it) online compilers

Comment: Pointers are variables that point to other variables. Which variable does sum point to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double *sum;
```

This creates a pointer to a `double` but it has an arbitrary value and therefore points at no dedicated memory.

In addition, in the called function, you set the `sum` pointer to zero (the null pointer) then try to use that pointer to dereference memory - that's a big non-no.

I'd also be wary of `for(i=0; i<n-2; i++)` for summing the values in the array. It's not going to include the final two which, since `n` is two, means it won't accumulate *any* of them.

The correct way to do this would be with:

```
void avg_sum(double a[], int n, double *avg, double *sum) {
    int i;
    *sum = 0;               // set content, not pointer.
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)      // do all elements.
        *sum += *(a+i);
    *avg = *sum/n;
}

int main(void) {
    double arr[2] = {0.0,1.0};
    double sum;                  // ensure actual storage
    double avg;                  // and here
    int n = 2;
    avg_sum(arr, n, &avg, &sum); // then pass pointers to actual storage

    printf("Sum=%f, Avg=%f\n", sum, avg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

This gives you, as expected:

```
Sum=1.000000, Avg=0.500000
```

Comment: still getting segmentation fault... :(

Comment: @PlutonianFairy: then you haven't made all the corrections I suggested. The new code works fine, that final output line is from an actual run of it.

Comment: worked when also changed sum = 0; to *sum = 0; after changing the main loop, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easy. In line 6 you assign 0 to `sum` but sum is not the actual sum but a pointer to it. When you try to print it you access invalid memory.

Edit:
BTW if you try compling with -fanalyzer you will get a warning and an explanation.
https://godbolt.org/z/W6ehh8

Comment: i changed it to *sum = 0; and changed the main () as told by @paxdiablo, now it works :), Thanks

Comment: @PlutonianFairy As a sign of gratitude you could accept paxdiablo's answer. :)